# Can't Override onPostExecute() method in AsyncTask Class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, return, return-value

I know there are several question which are quite similar to this one, but they didn't helped me so far. I'm still not able to override this AsyncTasks.
Can you hel me?

I already made sure that doInBackground() devlivers some type that onPostExecute() requires (Boolean in the first and JSON in the second example).

Do you see anything except that i extend AsyncTask as raw type (was not sure about what to enter here)

This is the error eclipse tells me for each method:

> The method onPostExecute(Boolean) of type Register.NetCheck must override or implement a supertype method

and for the classes eclipse tells me:

> - The type Register.NetCheck must implement the inherited abstract  method AsyncTask.doInBackground(Object...)
> - AsyncTask is a raw type. References to generic type AsyncTask should be 
>      parameterized

EXAMPLE 1:

```
private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
            do.something();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground (String... args){
               if (do.something.worked){
                   return true; }
               else { return false}
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){
            evalute.input.boolValue();
        }
    }
```

EXAMPLE 2:

```
private class ProcessRegister extends AsyncTask {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            show.some.dialog();
        }
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONObject json = generate.some.json();
            return json;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
           evaluate.something();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your async task is not expecting a return value, so it does not recognise

```
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th)
```

Try this instead:

```
private class NetCheck extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        do.something();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground (String... args){
           if (do.something.worked){
               return true; }
           else { return false}
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean th){
        evalute.input.boolValue();
    }
}
```

Replace Boolean with JSONObject for the second example. Try to always use the IDE to automatically implement the methods for you, will avoid problems like this.

Comment: can you tell me why to use `doInBackground (Void... params)` instead of my version with `doInBackground (String... args)`.
Just for your notice: I copied that codesnippings from somewehere else and tried to fit it to me needings

Comment: Made the amendments @Krummy

Answer (score 1):

You should extend AsyncTask with types. See example below.

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Integer> {
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
        super.onPostExecute(integer);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(Integer integer) {
        super.onCancelled(integer);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }
}
```

Replaces Void, String, Integer with apropriate types. More info is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).
About Eclipse. Delete in and install [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

Comment: can you explain me why shell i use the types `<void, void, void>` instead of e.g. `<String, Object, Boolean>` or like the one with the other answer said `<Void, Void, Boolean>`?

Comment: The first parameter, String indicates that you will be passing a string as a parameter into the task when executed, the second, Object, represents the progress units that will be published while the task is being executed, and the third represents what the type of result the async task will produce

Comment: I just understood this whole thing a lot more since a few minutes ago! :D

Thank you ver much for your very speedy response!

Comment: This should work find now: `onPostExecute(JSONObject s)`